# Spree override the partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, overriding, partial-views, spree

Can I in spree app `deface` partial? But not a single element. I need override all of the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace whole templates. See the [guides under the section "Template Replacements"](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/view.html#template-replacements).

For example add your own file in `YOUR_SITE/app/views/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb`

and it will replace the one used by Spree when the page is rendered.